# MySQL resource usage

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm using MySQL with PHP. I want to measure how much memory and other resources MySQL is using when I run a particular query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you cannot do this in PHP. However, if you are afraid that you are consuming too much memory with your queries, you can use [`mysql_free_result( );`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-free-result.php).

```
$result = ... first query

mysql_free_result( $result ); // Frees memory

$next_result = ... next query
```